# proportional height of view and superview autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a small view that I want him occupy 1/3 height of superview(same size with safe area)

I defined leading space, trailing space, bottom space which its constant = 0 with superview.bottom.

AND I want to make the height 1/3 of superview height to make it same look in all iphone sizes. I defined aspect ratio and changed its first item as superview.height and second item as thisview.height. of course I have defined 3:1 multiplier
[image]
[image]

But it doesnt work it gives following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's
>   illegal.

Come on!! why doesnt it work? this is not that complex compared to all other stuff. 
Also how can I complish this on interface. (not in code) I would like to see it on xcode with all other screensizes in preview tab.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: please share how you set this view constraints , properly IB screenshoots

Comment: Share your autolayout code for the view and other relevant views.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the view `Equal Heights` with its superview. Then change the multiplier of the `Equal Heights` constraint to 1:3

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ricky. I see where I was messing up now :) I tried that with height constraint and couldnt see that multiplier there. Now I see where the equal height or equal width come to the area. thanks a lot. I cant tell how much time I have wasted to make that up. Regards