# Scale content to device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I created simple view to FlashCards, but when I try put autolayout on sign i have a problem. In xcode small white view size works fine, but when i run apps in simulator size is crashed. I have assets 2x and 3x. I tried make bigger view in xcode but when i do this view works fine on ip8, but ip8+ is too large [image: view in xcode]
here sign is bigger than my view, and view dont masks sign.

[image]

but iphon 8+ works fine...
[image]

its my small white view contrains
[image]

well background is imageview with this img
[image]
, next i added white uiview on sign (which size is crashed), in next step i want add this sign: [image] in white view to flips and changes words, all works fine when i created layout on one device, but when i try added autolayout size white view and content in this view is crashed

Comment: It depends on what your autolayout constraints are. You have given no information about that.

Comment: @matt oh sorry i forgot about this, already added.

Comment: And what about the content mode of the palm tree image view?

Comment: in all elements is scale to fill, because scall to fit make my sign to small, but i tried scall to fit and size is still broken...

Comment: So the sign is also an image view? Containing what? A white image? Please try to give _information_.

Comment: @matt i described my problem, and i created new project only this one view, if u want i can gives you link to this project, meaby this help?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this is to **increase** your current **height** and **width** **values** and then test it through all device screen sizes. Fingers crossed that you going to get wished result.

A second solution, which requires graphic editor software skils, is that you separate the sign from the current image, without background, let's say in Photoshop. And then use the sign image as the second image, which is located in separate ImageView. Position this sign Image View over current background Image View( with palms ) to fit your wished layout. Set leading, trailing and bottom constraints for sign Image View, and at the end set proportional height constant which is proportional to the screen height of your device.

If you screen height is 667, and your sign Image View height is 150, result is that your new sign Image View should be 22.48875562% height size of your device screen height size. See [Proportional height of view and superview autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551823/proportional-height-of-view-and-superview-autolayout)
 for more details about proportional layout with swift.

And now you should add your UIView over sign Image View. When you've added UIView set top, leading and trailing constraints to be same as the constraints of sign Image View. And at the end, add another proportional height constraint which is proportional to the height of sign Image View.

The first solution is easy, and the second one is tricky, but I hope it helps. It's always tricky to sync UI elements with graphic parts of images.

Comment: well i do this, i try set height and width, but this dont help, i have separated sign and i want adds this in whiteView, but size this sign is crushed, i described this in first post, if u want i shared this single view in xcode project and gives link

Comment: Try with proportional size values. Set the proportional height of sign Image View in relation to height value of your view and remove bottom constraint of your sign Image View.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Reason break this view is tabbar, I created layout on view where i don't see tabbar. When I run apps and tabbar is shown view is smaller and constraints are break content.